# Footable not loading

Tags: javascript, footable

I am using the Footable plug-in.It shows an error in console: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined".

I have used following steps,

1. Added gem 'footable-rails' in GemFile
2. In Application.css:

   ```
    *= require_self
    *= require datepicker
    *= require datetimepicker
    *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
    *= require DT_bootstrap
    *= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
    *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
    *= require jquery.timepicker
    *= require footable-rails
    *= require_tree .
   ```
3. Application.js:

   ```
   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require jquery.ui.datepicker
   //= require twitter/bootstrap
   //= require bootstrap-datepicker
   //= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
   //= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
   //= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
   //= require jquery.timepicker.js
   //= require rails.validations
   //= require rails.validations.custom
   //= require rails.validations.simple_form
   //= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
   //= require highcharts
   //= require exporting
   //= require footable-rails
   //= require_tree .
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On what line of what file does the error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this same error, and it was because I had multiple `footables` on the same page, and basically the second table was overwriting the first table. So the reason I was getting the error is because I was trying to sort on a `columnindex` that didn't exist in the second table.

Anyway, I reported it as a bug https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable/issues/132, and it has been fixed, so if your having the same issue that I was having, re-download `V2` and that should fix it.